# Let $C$ a no empty class of subset of $X$. Prove all set generated $\sigma$-ring by $C$ is a subset of a countable union of set of $C$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C$ a no empty class of subset of $X$. Prove all set generated $\sigma$-ring  by $C$ is a subset of a countable union of set of $C$.

**My attempt:**

Let $C$ a non empty class of set of X.

Let $R(C)$ the $\sigma$-ring generated by C.

Let $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in R(C)$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\in C.$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?